# Avoid user interaction on "disabled" table row

Tags: html, css

I've got an HTML table which has some of its rows 'disabled'. I'd like to show it clearly to the user, so I apply a blur filter to the `tr`, having a table like this:

[image]

NOTE: There's a live example on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdypks.

The problem is that, although it looks disabled, the user still can interact with it, selecting the text and clicking on the select input. Also, some of the cells are droppable areas where I can drop objects, so I'd like to avoid it.

I wouldn't like to use Javascript, so I wonder if there's a way to place a transparent DIV in front of the disabled `tr` or something similar...

Thanks!

Comment: just don't show the row. remove the data. Problem solved.

Comment: Even with all 3 of the answers below users will still be able to take and grab the data via "Inspect Element" on the browser console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `disabled` property is on the `tr`,
I think you can do the following:

```css
/* Some style */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

th {
  border: 0;
  padding: 2px 20px;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 8px 20px;
}

/*
  The below adds a veil ABOVE the td elements
  that are in a tr with the "disabled" property.
  If you click, that's on the veil, not on the button
*/
#table1 tr[disabled] td::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/*
  This shorter one should work too:
  It disables the events of your mouse on the tds
  that are in a tr with the "disabled" property.
  (Plus, I added your blur)
*/
#table2 tr[disabled] td {
  filter: blur(1px);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Not much indentation here only to make the code of the snippet shorter -->
<table id="table1">
  <tr><th>Order</th><th>Name</th><th>Occupation</th><th>Action</th></tr>
  <tr><td>#1</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td><button>Button</button></td></tr>
  <tr disabled><td>#2</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td><button>Button</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td>#3</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td><button>Button</button></td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<table id="table2">
  <tr><th>Order</th><th>Name</th><th>Occupation</th><th>Action</th></tr>
  <tr><td>#1</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td><button>Button</button></td></tr>
  <tr disabled><td>#2</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td><button>Button</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td>#3</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td><button>Button</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

Note that the button in the disabled row cannot be clicked.

`tr[disabled] td::after` adds a veil (using `::after` pseudo-element) after (so, above) the `td` elements that are in a `tr` with the "disabled" property.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for: simple and works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: And better to use class or data-attribute, because "disabled" not allowed for `tr`

Comment: Can't the user still interact with the row via the keyboard (starting with the Tab key)?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to disable some row, you can use `pointer-events: none` for this row. It's will prevent any events of mouse in your row.

```css
tr.disabled{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr>
<td><p style="user-select: none;">test</p></td>
<td><input type="button" disabled="disabled"></td>
</tr>
```

You can try this,
you even cant select them with doubleclick

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `disabled` attribute on form controls like so

```
<select disabled>
```

For text, follow this link: [How to disable text selection highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Answer (score -1):

A very cheap way to "disable" a table row (or anything else ):

```css
.disabled {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<tr class="disabled">
  ...
</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: This is just reducing the opacity of the items. It's not preventing users from interacting with the items.